Why am I unable to force-delete webp files using “del /f path” from command line "as administrator" on Windows 10 workstation?
How to delete a webp file downloaded onto a Windows 10 workstation? I've tried the command-line del /f  {path} from the command-line as administrator, and it doesn't work.
Neither can I rename the file to have a different extension. The file is not read-only according to Properties. What is preventing the deletion and how to circumvent it?
By doesn't work I mean several things:

The file is never deleted, no error message from command line.
If done from Windows Explorer the delete just runs forever and the little progress dialog never terminates until manually closed.


There is nothing special about WebP files that makes them difficult to remove. WebP is just an image file format, as are GIF, JPEG, and PNG.
The issue is that some process is locking that file, such as being open in a web browser.
There are a number of tools to see what is locking a file, or to unlock a file, either immediately, or after a reboot, to allow the locking app to close. Try Nirsoft's OpenedFilesView, Crystal Rich's LockHunter, or one of the many alternatives. Of course, before using a new application, check it at VirusTotal.

Thanks. To be fair, there are dozens and dozens of threads on the internet where people are having trouble deleting them on Windows 10, and some of the threads indicate that some nebulous "system settings" are resonsible. So,  I don't dispute what you've said, but it certainly looked as though there was something different about them.  You'd think that in 2024 Microsoft would have given me the same message when I tried to delete the file that File Explorer gave to me when I tried to rename the folder.

Microsoft's Process Explorer can be used as well, at least to find the PID of the process holding the file handle open so that you can kill that process, search for the filename in find > "handles and dlls". Explorer will occasionally barf when attempting to generate thumbnails and a COM process will hold the file(s) open.

I tried to rename the folder where the files where stored and got an error message that this was not possible because the folder was open in another program.  Yet I had no other programs open visibly on the desktop, so something was "stuck".  Rebooted. Was then able to rename the folder and delete the files.

FYI:
A dozen years ago I remember using a freeware tool called Unlocker
( https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlocker ) to avoid the mentioned reboot.
Nowadays even the Microsoft Powertoys toolbox includes  file-locksmith that should do the trick
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/file-locksmith
